# Difference between eclipse pulsar, mtj, me

Tags: eclipse, mtj

what is difference between eclipse pulsar, eclipse mtj, and eclipse me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Eclipse ME](http://eclipseme.org/) is an external project started in 2003. As its page says:

> **EclipseME has graduated to become the new [Eclipse Mobile Tools for Java (MTJ) project](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/)**.
>   The MTJ project provides all of the functionality from EclipseME 1.7.9 plus many new features and lots of bug fixes. The EclipseME project will remain open indefinitely**, but there will be no new releases of EclipseME**.

- Eclipse MTJ is part of the larger [DSDP (Device Software Development Platform)](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/) set of projects, which addresses a broad range of needs in the device software development space using the Eclipse platform.

MTJ  is a project which "will develop frameworks that can be extended by tool vendors and tools that can be used by third-party developers."

- [Eclipse Pulsar](http://www.eclipse.org/pulsar/) takes advantage of the MTJ framework and provides a "tools integration platform" (as opposed to "an Eclipse with a plugin for mobile development".
  It is a **[package (an Eclipse distribution)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/)**.

As [Chris Aniszczyk](http://aniszczyk.org/) says in his [blog post](http://aniszczyk.org/2009/06/11/eclipse-galileo-review/):

> The other new package is Pulsar which was built specifically for the Mobile Java community.
>   **Pulsar is essentially a mashup of the Eclipse SDK and the Eclipse MTJ projects with the ability of downloading more tools from different handset manufacturers.**

You can compare the [Pulsar package with other Eclipse packages here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages).

---

So:

External Plugin (ME) => official Eclipse project (MTJ) => Full Eclipse distribution (package, with Pulsar)