# eclipse mtj memory monitor

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, mtj

Please tell me how can i activate the Sun JavaME memory monitor within eclipse mtj.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure there is a *direct* integration of that tool in Eclipse.

You can try with a fresh installation of **[Eclipse Pulsar](http://www.eclipse.org/pulsar/)** (which [includes MTJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639730/difference-between-eclipse-pulsar-mtj-me)),

- develop your J2ME project here
- see if [eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) cannot get a similar service than Sun J2ME Memory Analzer

if not, you can try and run your project made with Pulsar directly under a [Sun Wireless Toolkit](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Java_ME_Quick_Start#Sun_Wireless_Toolkit) project, which does include the memory monitor utility.

[alt text http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/images/7/7c/WTK_Utilities.png](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/images/7/7c/WTK_Utilities.png)