# How to uninstall an eclipse plug-in through code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to uninstall eclipse plug-in through code. I don't want to use the eclipse provided option.
I want to code the logic behind it in Java. I wrote the code to delete the required plug-in from plug-in dir and feature as well but still the name of the plug-in is getting displayed in Eclipse Uninstall option.

Answer (score 2):

You need org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.UninstallOperation

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact mechanism, but [this (2009) code](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=136228) about [uninstalling an MTJ module](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=271767).
(See [Difference between eclipse pulsar, mtj, me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639730/difference-between-eclipse-pulsar-mtj-me)).

Even if it involves some GUI (Uninstall Wizards), it is calling some p2 code (like a [p2 `PlannerResolutionOperation`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5/org.eclipse.equinox.p2/ui/1.0.100/org/eclipse/equinox/internal/provisional/p2/ui/operations/PlannerResolutionOperation.java)), which can give some clue as to how remove a module through p2 in Java code.